# Myapp is crashing when trying to change font in ios8

Tags: ios, swift, crash

This line is working perfect at ios 9 but when I try it on ios 8 its crashing and says

```
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

so what should I do for this. This is my code.

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName:UIColor.blackColor(),NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: ".SFUIDisplay-Bold", size: 18)!]
```

Comment: It's not. I know what should I do when my data or object returns nil. But its different code its working in ios 9 but its not working ios 8. I'm trying to understand why its returning nil on ios 8

Comment: Can you please do some debugging and figure out exactly which call is returning `nil`?

Comment: Duplicate. `UIFont(name: ".SFUIDisplay-Bold", size: 18)!` UIFont returns nil, you're force unwrapping: crash.